# Selecting / grouping by first character string until a specific symbol

Tags: r, pattern-matching, grouping

Good day,

I'm currently working on a dataset where theres a column in this format.

PA-121-1512-asa-1241
PWW-121-1571-accs-21561
PSAWA-171-1616-gfaa-161
QSF-16-1613-63-asdfa
H-Elevator-15-asf-1112
QSF-asa-sda-afas-112

The first sequence of letters before the "-" symbol is identified as "building location" Due to this i would like to save these first sequence of letters in a seperate column.

I would like to know how to select > copy > paste these values in a new column so i end up with a column like e.g.:

Location:
PA
PPW
PSAWA
QSF
H
QSF

I tried the function:

```
str_extract("PA-121-1512-asa-1241", ".+?(?<=-)")
```

The PA-121-1512-asa-1241 is a example i selected the whole column.
Here what i got printed out was PA- instead of just PA.

If more data a more elaborate explenation is needed please do tell me. Im still fairly new to writing questions on this site.

Happy hollidays!,
E.D.D.

Post post...
After looking at my code again to copy paste a propper example as Mr. Cyrus suggested, I've found my mistake. instead of:

```
str_extract("PA-121-1512-asa-1241", ".+?(?<=-)")
```

it is:

```
str_extract("PA-121-1512-asa-1241", "[^-]+")
```

This returns PA instead of PA-
This shows that reading trough your code 50x does help because the previous 49 didnt.

If anyone has a more elegant / efficient method, I'm still interested! Since running this code trough 5million rows took me quite a while.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Also along with what Cyrus sir has mentioned, please always do wrap your samples/codes in CODE TAGS for better visibility in question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:
str_extract("PA-121-1512-asa-1241", ".+?(?<=-)") it is
str_extract("PA-121-1512-asa-1241", "[^-]+")
This returns "PA" instead of "PA-"
This shows that reading trough your code 50x does help because the previous 49 didnt.

str_extract() required format for the "pattern" is quite confusing to get right. Reading more into Grep has been advised to me by my teacher.